# how to implement pop-up code for multiple buttons on the screen in the android?

Tags: android

As I am beginner, I am able to implement the pop-up code for single button that is pasted below..

Requirement: I need to implement multiple pop-up's to show different text(information) on each pop-up.

```
public void init() {
popupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
popupText = new TextView(this);
insidePopupButton = new Button(this);
layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout lt=new LinearLayout(this);
view=new ScrollView(this);
insidePopupButton.setText("OK");
popupText.setText("This is Popup Window.press OK to dismiss it.");
popupText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
popupText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
layoutOfPopup.setOrientation(1);
lt.addView(popupText);
layoutOfPopup.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
layoutOfPopup.addView(view);
layoutOfPopup.addView(insidePopupButton,350,50);
view.addView(lt);
}
public void popupInit() {
popupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
insidePopupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
popupMessage = new PopupWindow(layoutOfPopup, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
popupMessage.setContentView(layoutOfPopup);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.textview1) {
popupMessage.showAsDropDown(popupButton, 0, 0);
}

else {
popupMessage.dismiss();
}
}

   }
```

and my requirement is showing through the image.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of these 'pop-up's'?

Comment: I want show some text on that pop-up and at the end of the pop-up there will be a close button to close the pop-up. Similarly for second button also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch case for handle click on other views.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId())
   {
    case R.id.textview1:
    case R.id.textview2:
    case R.id.textview3:
    case R.id.textview4: popupMessage.showAsDropDown(popupButton, 0, 0);
                         break;
    default:popupMessage.dismiss();
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dialog fragment and design a layout that will contain all of the required buttons that you need.

Comment: Pardon. Did you understand my requirement?

Comment: When the first button is clicked it should launch a dialog fragment. This dialog fragment can take up the whole screen depending on your layout. Using this method you would able to have the full screen appear and contain anything that may be required on this new screen.

Comment: After closing one pop-up of one button,My requirement is  to open another pop-up of another button in same screen.

Comment: each button can contain a different fragment

Comment: Thank you..can you please enhance the code according to that if possible or give any other example code by that I'll do further because literally I don't know how to use dialog fragment.